# Is there a good tidyverse equivalent of `[()` for subsetting within a pipe?

Tags: r, pipe

I'm after a more elegant tidyverse equivalent for `[()` that works for piping and in chains of pipes. I'm tempted to just wrap around it with my own function, because I ideally want all the functionality for it (working for different datatypes, matrices, vectors, dataframes etc).

```
piped_subset <- function(x, ...) `[`(x, ...)
```

So for example, using this function, the following operations all work.

```
mat <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5) 
vec <- LETTERS[1:25]
df <- ToothGrowth
l <-  list(vec)

mat %>% piped_subset(1, 2)
vec %>% piped_subset(24)
df %>% piped_subset(1, 2)
l %>% piped_subset(1) #not very useful here, but works.
```

But I'd be happier if there was a solution out there in one of the common packages, so I'm doing something a little more standard. Any ideas?

- I'm aware of `subset()` but for the selection of rows you have to use a logical (and I'm not sure how to access row numbers), so `mat %>% subset(1, 2)` doesn't work.
- I'm aware of `filter()` and `select()`, but it takes two steps with them, and it doesn't work on matrices.
- I'm aware of `pluck()` and `purr()` from `dplyr` but they do too little. So you have to chain a few together. Plus they don't work on matrices (well pluck does, but not in a useful way).
- I'm aware that I can use `` `[`() `` but that's just ugly.

Comment: There still is `slice()` (similar to subset, but works with line indices) which would have to be combined in a pipe with `select()` to achieve the same thing. This also only works with certain datatypes, so it is by no means as versatile what you already achieved.

Comment: I often use the square bracket in back-ticks as a function directly rather than wrapping it in another function. Such as ```df %>% `[`(1, 2)```

Comment: I do that too @Allan, but it hurts my soul a little, so am happy to hear below of `magrittr::extract()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `magrittr::extract`, the source code of which is just [`` extract <- `[` ``](https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/blob/80c262100ef88ddc2bde74896632e0286b5cee6a/R/aliases.R#L60)

(Not to be confused with `tidyr::extract`, so a note of caution in case `tidyr` is loaded)

From `help(extract, magrittr)`:

> magrittr provides a series of aliases which can be more pleasant to use when composing chains using the %>% operator.

Comment: Oh, excellent this is exactly what I was after. Thankyou! And of course using an alias is smarter than wrapping the function like I did!

Answer (score 2):

`` %>% `[`(...) `` is the same thing as `` %>% `[`(., ...) `` using an explicit dot, and the latter is strictly equivalent to `%>% .[...]` after parsing. So you can simply use `%>% .[...]` :

```r
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  .[1:2,] %>% 
  .[,4:5]
#>   Petal.Width Species
#> 1         0.2  setosa
#> 2         0.2  setosa

mat <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5) 
vec <- LETTERS[1:25]
df <- ToothGrowth
l <-  list(vec)

mat %>% .[1,2]
#> [1] 6
vec %>% .[24]
#> [1] "X"
df %>% .[1,2]
#> [1] VC
#> Levels: OJ VC
l %>% .[1]
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S"
#> [20] "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than `\`[\`(...)`. Thankyou.